# Ionic - custom directive blocks scrolling in modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

[image: Friends in a modal view]

The screenshot above shows a list of friends in a modal view. Custom directives `avatar-button` are arranged in rows and columns. Each `avatar-button` consists of an image and a text paragraph. The directive `avatar-button` is also used in other navigation views.

When I test my application on an Android mobile device, the modal view cannot be scrolled if I start the scrolling gesture on any `avatar-button`. However, the modal view can be scrolled if I touch the screen on somewhere which is not covered by a `avatar-button`. It seems my custom directive blocks or consumes my scrolling gesture, and therefore the scroll event cannot be propagated to `<ion-content>` which is declared in the `<ion-modal-view>` tag.

No problem is found whenever the scrolling gesture starts on top of any `avatar-button` in other navigation views though.

How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use `event.stopPropagation()` or `event.preventDefault()` in your directive? What is the computed CSS style?

You can also try following things:

1. Disable scrolling from ionic and use the native scrollbar and see if this helps:

> ```
> app.config([
>     "$ionicConfigProvider", function ($ionicConfigProvider) {
>         $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
>     }
> ]);
> ```

2. You also could disable scrolling for a custom ionic-content element, with this directive:

   `overflow-scroll='false'`

Information about this is here:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/

Maybe you can post some code from your directive for more detailed help.

Greets,
Stefan

Comment: Thanks, adding `overflow-scroll="false"` to `<ion-content>` in `<ion-modal-view>` works.

Comment: In my case only works with the second option, Why? Is there any point to consider? Thanks!

Comment: Check if your config is called and isn't been overridden. And you or someone else didn't write some directives above **overflow-scroll="true"**